# Multi-picklist validation rule - if multiple values chosen includes a certain value throw error

Tags: validation-rule

I want to create a validation rule that validates the selection made by the user on a multi picklist field.
If the user chooses value "b" from the list of options throw an error saying value "b" cannot be combined with other options, This is what I tried so far, getting an error.

```
IF(INCLUDES(theField, "a"),1,0)+
IF(INCLUDES(theField, "b"),1,0)+
IF(INCLUDES(theField, "c"),1,0)+
IF(INCLUDES(theField, "d"),1,0)+
&&
IF(INCLUDES(theField, "b"),1,0)+
```

What I did, in plain words, if the user chose more than one item from the multi-picklist field and if the selection contains value b, throw error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an `AND` for the top level comparison and an `OR` for the remaining items that cannot be included if the first is selected. Like this:

```
AND(  INCLUDES(theField,"b"),
      OR ( INCLUDES(theField,"a"),
           INCLUDES(theField,"c"),
           INCLUDES(theField,"d"))  
)
```

Note: I left `b` out of the `OR` group, because this would always cause an error, meaning you could never save if `b` was selected.

Comment: Thanks Casper for helping out.